# Docker take advantage of several base images

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

New to docker, I'm trying to learn best practises over it.

Here's my situation : I've got a website, based uppon [yeoman generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular).

I want to create a Dockerfile (to place inside my project) that would basically do the following :

- Build the project with **nodejs**
- Serve the output with **nginx**

It seems that both [nodejs](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/baad247b9df8087d4c13a3a9bfb3c65833f424bb/5.10/wheezy/Dockerfile) and [nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/19799fa644461ed6c5ea07c0bc0ea0cc277c2d77/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile) base images deal great stuff (that I wouldn't want to copy/paste from their Dockerfile), and would be worth inheriting from. Indeed, I want to respect official nginx installation logic and also want to keep nodejs official image inheritance about buildpack-deps and stuff.

---

The question is :

***How would I take advantage of two distincts base images without having to copy paste their content ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic premise of Docker is that each container does a single job. So in your case you would deploy your nodejs container to build (and run) the project. Then you would create an nginx container that is connected to it (either though the network or a docker volume) that then serves that data to the network.

This let's you update each singular aspect of the solution safe in the knowledge that you won't have any impact on any other component.

To answer your actual question, I don't think there is a way outside of hacking the two together by hand.

There are a LOT of nodejs / nginx / docker tutorials online that go through the whole process.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Definately not the answer I expected but well, it allows me to take advantage of both images, and seems like a good practise =) I'd lose "all included" stuff there, but it seems more like a design misconception of mine now. Thanks

Comment: (Concerning nginx + node tuts, most of them get rid of official images, reinventing the wheel in the process. Many are very outdated too, using deprecated stuff like `link`)

Comment: The good part about Docker is how easy it is to modify a deployment, if you find a Dockerfile that mostly does what you need it is trivial to strip out  or add to it to get what you need. I've never actually followed any of the Node and Nginx tutorials, they just seem to be at the end of every search I do for anything that has docker in it

Comment: Obviously right about deployment easy modification. But official images have 2 pros : clever guys (Well, more "system" oriented guys, linux ninjas) have put together some great stuff that I wouldn't dare overriding, being developer myself; and those images have releases, that I can easily change in my FROM clause, whereas copy pasting their dockerfile doesn't allow this)

Comment: As you get more comfortable using Docker you will be more inclined to roll your own Dockerfiles - and of course any Dockerfile can be based on any other Dockerfile. So if there is one that you like you can base yours on that and it will get its updates along the way.